# Is "youtubeBRwatch.com.exe" a Virus?

Tags: mac, virus, anti-virus, malware, norton-antivirus

I am running Norton AntiVirus on my MacBook Pro with OSX 10.6.7. Today (26 May 2011) Norton reported that the computer was infected with virus "youtubeBRwatch.com.exe," which it had "safely quarantined but could not repair."

I Googled "youtubeBRwatch" but can find only this reference. http://www.prevx.com/filenames/2159897571621317258-X1/YOUTUBEBRWATCH.COM.html
Previx claims to be a subsidiary of Webroot. That could be true, or it could be a malware site pushing fake cleaner software, and falsely claiming to be a subsidiary of Webroot, for all I know.

A search for youtubeBRwatch on the Norton website returned nothing.

What is youtubeBRwatch.com.exe? Is it really malware, or is this a false positive from Norton Antivirus?

I do see that youtubeBRwatch.com.exe shows up in my Downloads directory, which is highly suspicious since I certainly never requested to download such a file. Is this new malware that can somehow force a download by your browser through an attack against Flash or something?

Comment: This is just some advice... I would not run Nortn Antivirus on anything. I would not run any antivirus on a Mac. Mac's are not targets for viruses. Windows is the target. I know I am probably stirring up something with someone, but this is just a helpful tip to speed up your computer and save a lot of money.

Comment: Macs are just as vulnerable to many virus/spyware issues. There are plenty of free options out there that are low overhead. I do however agree with ditching Norton though, never been a fan.

Comment: Not trying to be doom and gloom @David. But to say there is no such thing as a virus on a Mac is being Naive. http://it.slashdot.org/story/11/05/26/1355243/Mac-Malware-Evolves---No-Install-Password-Required

Comment: @David: that is some pretty bad advice there. Just because MacOS is not usually the target and may be more difficult to attack, does not mean it is never the target and is impossible to attack (even a system completely unbreakable without user intervention is at risk to "human engineering". Search for news of macdefender and its family of self-installing malware for instance.

Comment: Indeed, as there is now a case of widespread malware in the wild on OS X, "macs don't get viruses" is simply not acceptable any more.

Comment: Sorry @Nixphoe for your failure to communicate. If you actually read my comment, I never said there weren't viruses for Macs. And @DavidSpilett, for any user that has common sense using a Mac, or Linux, you can avoid viruses pretty easily. Don't do stupid stuff like clicking on random advert's. Also, go to only safe sites. If you aren't tech savvy you should use some type of virus protection with ANY OS(maybe that is a better way to put it). Sorry for those of you who were highly offended by my choice of words...

Comment: @David; The problem I have with your comment is ideological. While it's true now, OS X is not **inherently** more secure than Windows (See: every pwn2own), and while it hasn't been a major target for viruses, that's actually changing before our eyes. There's at least one major case of malware, as well as mac variants of the `make-your-own-malware` kits starting to appear. It isn't much of a target now, but that could well change in the immediate future.

Comment: @Phoshi, thanks for the info. I didn't know that. I do not personally use Macs, but I have set up iMac labs recently and know many IT engineers that use Macs. I have talked to them about the safety of Macs, and they tend to think the same way I did. Thank you for enlightening me on the possible upcoming threat to Mac users.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the file.

http://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/updated-macdefender-malware-appears-no-longer-needs-password-052611

Answer (score 0):

This virus was written for Windows, so will probably do nothing having it on your Mac anyway. However, you should delete it anyway. If you're not sure where it came from, you can right click and get info and if it was downloaded with Safari/Chrome on OS X then it should show you the origin domain name/IP.